# RecyclerView isn't displaying any items

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

My recyclerView isn't displaying any items. I'm not getting any errors though so I'm not sure what the problem is. Here is the code.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.recyclerviewexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView contactsRecView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactsRecView = findViewById(R.id.contactsRecView);

        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        contacts.add(new Contact("Tony Soprano", "tsoprano@gmail.com", "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/13/a9/41/13a9416d23220f57191bbdb9a0eab3aa.jpg"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Silvio Dante", "sdante@gmail.com", "https://i1.wp.com/bamfstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sop603silv-main1.jpg?ssl=1"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Paulie Gualtieri", "pgualtieri@gmail.com", "http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110422182403/sopranos/images/c/c5/Paulie1.jpg"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Salvatore Bonpensiero", "sbonpensiero@gmail.com", "https://static1.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Big-Pussy-in-The-Sopranos.jpg"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Christopher Moltisanti", "cmoltisanti@gmail.com", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/9b/bd/6d/9bbd6d2c6cd5c285f6d537e82fcbea80.jpg"));

        ContactsRecViewAdapter adapter = new ContactsRecViewAdapter();
        adapter.setContacts(contacts);

        contactsRecView.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        contactsRecView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    }
}
```

ContactsRecViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.recyclerviewexample;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactsRecViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsRecViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    public ContactsRecViewAdapter() {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtName.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void setContacts(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtName;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);

        }
    }
}
```

Contact.java

```
package com.example.recyclerviewexample;

public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String imageUrl;

    public Contact(String name, String email, String imageUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", imageUrl='" + imageUrl + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I am using the codeacademy tutorial on android studio and followed the section of recyclerView exactly to get this but it didn't display any items in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ContactsRecViewAdapter` you are returning `getItemCount` as `0`, which tells recycler how many items to render

```
  @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }
```